# Messed up .Bash my profile

Tags: git, macos, path

So being new at this I didn't realize the implication of installing various Git items kind of how I saw fit but now Im trying to install AWSEBCLI to manage my AWS site directly from my computer.

I just get command not found for basically any and all requests. Now I did find something online that made me be able to reset my .bash_profile to

/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

but despite it now being this nothing works. Is that because all of the things I've installed now don't have a path? If so how do I correct it or do I jsut reinstall it.

Comment: first, can you do and give the result of an `echo $PATH`. Maybe you did a wrong affectation in your bashrc or your bash_profile.

Comment: I think more information in your description to your question would help others help. Are you using Bash on a Linux, Ubuntu, OSX machine? You mention being "new to this". New to which; Unix, python, AWSEBCLI, Git hub, all four? What sort of python install have you done, so others have some idea of likelihood you have other required python dependencies installed. I find myself swimming around with a lot of possibilities and uncertainties without more details.  Oh and welcome Samuel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the executable's path in PATH variable inside your .bashrc file if it already doesn't exists. Then you need to run `source ~/.bashrc` to reflect the changes in same terminal or open a new terminal